Are there any notes on the plot of Netochka Nezvanova?
I just finished reading Fyodor Dostoevsky’s work Netochka Nezvanova, and I am left a bit sad that it is over. Primarily since I want to know how the book ends, I am aware that Dostoevsky never finished this work (after all he was exiled to Siberia for five years), but I want to know how the story ends as the ending made me want to keep reading. I know that authors tend  to have notebooks where they keep track of ideas, themes, and major plot points they want to explore through a novel. I don’t know if anyone happens to know if there are any for Netochka Nezvanova (either in Russian or translated to English) that would tell me how the story ends (I know it might be a longshot, but I thought I would ask).

There are surviving notebooks by Dostoevsky, but bar one manuscript from Siberia all are from the 1860s and after, particularly covering Crime And Punishment, The Idiot, The Possessed, and Raw Youth, together with some unpublished works. However there are some published letters; I'm not sure if any of them make reference. There's not a lot of scholarship about NN compared with other of his work, but maybe someone else can find something.

After returning from Siberia, Dostoevsky himself decided against finishing the work. In fact, while reworking the text for standalone publication, he even excluded a whole character of the

 orphan named Larenka

amongst other unresolved hooks.
(Source: annotation by G. M. Fridlender)
All that suggests that any information regarding the initial plans, discarding the probability that it had already been lost by the time of Dostoevsky’s release, is actually irrelevant to the final edition of the work.

From the Wikipedia article:

Netochka Nezvanova (Russian: Не́точка Незва́нова) is an unfinished novel by Fyodor Dostoevsky. It was originally intended as a large scale work in the form of a 'confession', but a background sketch of the eponymous heroine's childhood and adolescence is all that was completed and published. According to translator Jane Kentish, this first publication was intended as "no more than a prologue to the novel".1 Dostoevsky began work on the novel in 1848 and the first completed section was published at the end of 1849. Further work was prevented by the author's arrest and exile to a Siberian detention camp for his part in the activities of the Petrashevsky Circle. After his return in 1859, Dostoevsky never resumed work on Netochka Nezvanova, leaving this fragment forever incomplete.

So, according to this explanation, not only that the story is not finished, it might not even be properly started (being, presumably, only a "Prologue", or "fragment").
Let's remember that The Brothers Karamazov has roughly 900 pages, while "War and peace" by Tolstoy has more than 1225 pages. So what could follow after the ~175 pages of "Netochka Nezvanova", we cannot even speculate. Was it supposed to be a short story, similar to "The Idiot"? Or a competition (size-wise) against "Ramayana"?
Even if we find a note with some information (I hope something will be found, if not already found), we cannot speculate what could have been written, if the history would have been different.
I have similarly strong feelings of sadness and unfulfillment about the abrupt ending of "The Good Soldier Švejk" by Jaroslav Hašek.

I doubt that this provides any information that the OP didn't already know. Also, about "it is not even properly started": the currently available translation published by Penguin is 176 pages long. Is that what you mean by "not even properly started"?

@Tsundoku: A prologue is an introduction, before the actual story (hence, "not properly started"). While important to the development, it usually only provides some background information. Additionally, if the text available is only a prologue, the we cannot talk about the end of the story, but we can talk about the end of the introduction. And the end of the prologue is the actual story. Considering that "War and peace" has more than 1225 pages, 176 pages is definitely short. And the information is not my interpretation it is the opinion of the people who definitely know more than me.

@Tsundoku: I do not want to speculate on what OP already knows or does not know. I look forward to him dropping a comment.

The comparison with Tolstoy's War and Peace is not helpful. Dostoyevsky wrote several novels that are shorter than 250 pages, such as The Double, The Gambler and Notes From The Underground. And the answer does not actually answer the question, which is whether any notes on the plot have survived. The OP already knew the novel was unfinished.

My understanding is that OP has a feeling that the novel is mostly finished (and just the final end missing), when in fact it might be very far from that. So my answer, even though possibly incomplete, is not that useless. And if you want to focus on the short stories, please be free to do that. But I offered "The Brothers Karamazov" as a proof that Dostoevsky, just like Tolstoy, was not at all afraid of big works. So we cannot tell if the 176 pages were to be followed by only 20 pages, or by another 1000 pages.
